# Is it possible single Box App to authenticate different iOS apps?

Tags: objective-c, box-api

The whole idea is to authenticate `App`, `App Lite`, `App iPhone`, `App iPhone Lite` with single `Box.com App ID` and return the user to the right app which redirected to the user to the authorization/authentication web site.

My Conclusion till now leads to using different App Id, because of lack of option to add different `Redirect url's` and respectively possibility for [box-api] to recognize the right caller application.

Will it work if I try to embed auth url in UIWebView and handle the response from that webView?

Comment: You need separate Box app ids. What benefit do you perceive by sharing the same id with all of the related apps?

Comment: What's the sense of having 4 or 5 Box App for same application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We currently don't support this use case, and you'll need separate App IDs